# Converting from void * to use htonl

Tags: c, void-pointers, htonl

I have a void * value in a structure and I need to send it through a socket to a server. I know I need to use

```
int value = htonl(kv->value);
```

but the compiler is throwing errors

```
passing argument 1 of ‘htonl’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Werror]
```

I also tried casting the void * to an int, did not work and I used

```
htonl(*kv->value);
```

but that also threw errors. How do I get the void * to the right data type?

Side note: The structure is not editable as I am writing a framework.

```
struct kvpair {
    void *value;
};
```

Comment: What does the `void*` actually represent in your code? What exactly are you pointing at that needs to be sent over the network? `htonl()` and `ntohl()` only works on integers, not on pointers. *IF* the `void*` contains the actual integer value itself, rather than pointing at an integer elsewhere in memory, then you can type-cast the `void*` as-is, eg: `uint32_t value = htonl((uint32_t)(kv->value));` *IF* the `void*` points at an integer elsewhere in memory, you need to type-cast the pointer and then dereference it to get the pointed value, eg: `uint32_t value = htonl(*(uint32_t*)(kv->value));`

Comment: A pointer value in one process has no meaning to another process.  What kind of data are you actually trying to pass around?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't dereference a `void *` type directly, you have to first cast it to something you can dereference and dereference that.

For example

```
uint32_t value = htonl(*(uint32_t *) kv->value);
```

This casting and dereferencing requires that `kv->value` actually points to something that is the type you try to cast it to. If, in your code, `kv->value` points to a single `short` value then the above cast and dereferencing will lead to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: This assumes the `void*` is pointing at a `long` variable stored elsewhere in memory.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Just added a note about that.

Comment: If the `void*` points at a `short` variable, then you need to cast the `void*` to a `short*` instead of a `uint32*`. You have to cast to the correct data type. But it is perfectly fine to pass a `short` value to `htonl()`, it will simply be extended to 32 bits. Otherwise, use `htons()` instead.